# What's the conversion between apparent magnitude and lux?

Tags: energy, visible-light, astronomy, units

I know the apparent magnitude of the sun, but I'd like the units in lux. Please also direct me to a reliable source if possible.

Comment: I'm not experienced with this, so please let me know if I have the wrong units. But, I think lux can be directly converted from magnitude

Answer (score 2):

We can convert from magnitude to lux using the equation 
$$
E_v=10^{(-14.18-M_v)/2.5}
$$

where $M_v$ is the apparent magnitude in the visible band, and $E_v$ is the illuminance in lux. You can read more about it on this page: http://stjarnhimlen.se/comp/radfaq.html#7.