# Brightness of the light source at twilight computation

Tags: visible-light, computational-physics, sun

I would like to determine the brightness of the light source at twilight based upon its apparent magnitude.
In the question here:
[What are the average wavelengths and brightnesses of sunlight across the stages of twilight?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/410633/what-are-the-average-wavelengths-and-brightnesses-of-sunlight-across-the-stages)
we can find the query referring to the brightness of sunlight at different stages of twilight. Indeed, they're calculated well and published under this link:
https://stjarnhimlen.se/comp/radfaq.html#11
where the apparent magnitude of the Sun overhead is -26,7Mag.
Next, we have the other data, as listed in the screenshot below:
[image]

[image]
but as you can see, the overhead sun's stellar magnitude of -26.7Mag is crucial for all of them.
How they could look in a situation when the solar apparent magnitude could be lower  (eclipse-induced circumstances) with about -21Mag for example? What do all of these values look like?

I am looking for some decent formula or calculator, which could compute these values if it's any available.

**UPDATE:**

I found some hint here

[What's the conversion between apparent magnitude and lux?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340230/whats-the-conversion-between-apparent-magnitude-and-lux)

and the calculator here:
https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/vCalc/vMag+-+to+-+lux

but the calculator computes only the full values, no decimal are allowed.

I've tried the formula and put the solar magnitude of -26.77. Finally I got the result of about 108642Lux whereas the website here:
https://stjarnhimlen.se/comp/radfaq.html#11

says, that the Sun at zenith should give us about 130000Lux. The difference is quite large, what could be the reason behind it?

**UPDATE:**
https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/sun-lights-daytime-sky-average-surface-brightness-y-4-mag-asec2-apparent-brightness-sun-26-q43913905

This task reflects pretty much my question.

Comment: Your calculation agrees with another online source of sun illuminance: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/light-level-rooms-d_708.html.

I would recommend looking into established astronomy textbooks rather than website tables, though I sadly do not have any at hand to recommend to you

Comment: @Codename47 could you recommend some books i should look into?